# Was Jurassic Park's kitchen scene inspired by The War of the Worlds' Martian machine in the scullery?

Tags: jurassic-park, war-of-the-worlds

While reading "The Death of the Curate," chapter 4 of book 2 of H. G. Wells' *The War of the Worlds*, I couldn't help but notice a couple of parallels with the iconic *Jurassic Park* (1993) kitchen scene:

- Both WW's narrator and Hammond's grandchildren take refuge in a kitchen/scullery as the enemy approaches.
- The eyes of both the Martian machine and the velociraptor peering behind a glass.
- Latched doors are understood by both the Martian machine and the velociraptors.
- The Martian machine and the velociraptors each tapped at things.
- Both WW's narrator and Hammond's grandchildren flee the enemy.

The aforementioned prompted me to wonder if there is a canon/legend reference that expands on Jurassic Park's kitchen scene, which was inspired in part by the one in The War of the Worlds.

Interestingly, Steven Spielberg used a mirror reflection of the Martian machine in *War of the Worlds* (2005) as a nod to the one used in Jurassic Park with the velociraptor.